# What do these three options in a Cisco Router NAT configuration mean?

Tags: cisco, router, nat, cisco-ios, cisco-commands

In a standard Static PAT configuration, where one IP:Port combination is always mapped to another IP:Port combination, there are three possible combinations of inside/outside/source/destination that can be configured.

For example, this is a configuration example:

```
ip nat inside source static tcp 10.0.20.13 8080 2.2.2.33 80
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In layman's terms, this configuration allows any Outside host to initiate a TCP connection to the IP 2.2.2.33 over port 80.  When this packet hits the router, the *destination IP Address and Port* (`2.2.2.33:80`) gets translated to `10.0.20.13:8080`.

The reverse would also happen, if the inside host 10.0.20.13 sends a TCP packet with a source port of 8080, as this packet crosses the router, the *source IP and Port* (`10.0.20.13:8080`) gets translated to `2.2.2.33:80`.  (this would typically be a *response packet*, rather than one initiated from the Inside host)

---

Here are all the three configuration options for the marked portion above:

```
Router(config)#ip nat inside ?
  destination  Destination address translation
  source       Source address translation

Router(config)#ip nat outside ?
  source  Source address translation
```

In effect, you could configure:

- ip nat **inside source** static tcp {IP} {Port} {IP} {Port}
- ip nat **inside destination** static tcp {IP} {Port} {IP} {Port}
- ip nat **outside source** static tcp {IP} {Port} {IP} {Port}

How are these options different and when would one use each of the three options?  Please use layman's terms like I did above to describe how each would manipulate packets that were coming through the device.

Also, can anyone tell me why there is no **outside destination** option?

Comment: @Eddie, Rather than all of us regurgitating user manuals, take a look at this http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/network-address-translation-nat/13773-2.html or this http://www.groupstudy.com/archives/ccielab/200702/msg01284.html and see if that helps you.  After that, if you still have specific questions, we're happy to help.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We must start from the basics, so let's revise NAT terminology. NAT translates IP addresses in IP packets, right? What does that mean? That it, basically, creates mirages - yes, optical illusions, you know. For example, in a typical NAT configuration when private-addressed LAN hosts access Internet by using external router interface's public IP address those hosts appear for Internet servers as having this public IP (or IPs from a pool of public IPs). NAT does not create new physical hosts, of course - but it create kind of new virtual entities - in this example, the LAN hosts see themselves as, let's say 192.168.1.x but Internet servers see them as 203.0.113.x - one set of physical hosts but two sets of IP addresses. Two distinct sets of (logical) hosts. Optical illusion. And the terminology is this:

- **inside local** - "real" IP addresses of the internal hosts as assigned to their interfaces and as they see each other
- **inside global** - "mirage" IP addresses as seen by the outside world
- **outside global** - "real" IP addresses of the external hosts as they seen by themselves and by (almost) entire Internet
- **outside local** - "mirage" IP addresses as we see external hosts (if we asked NAT to translate correspondingly)

And as you can see, we are obliged to make a distinction between our network and the Internet or another external network. We do this by marking our router's IP interfaces as either **ip nat inside** or **ip nat outside**, agree?

Now let's remember how NAT is usually implemented: it maintains special tables that contain entries about translations. And the important point is that these entries can be created either *statically* or *dynamically*. For dynamically created entries, the direction of traffic is important - is the traffic initiated from inside to outside or vice versa? For static entries, this is not so - they are *symmetrical*. NAT configuration statements that contain the **static** keyword create static entries immediately after putting them into the running config; those with the **dynamic** keyword watch for the interesting traffic and dynamically create translation entries, which will then eventually time out.

We can already speculate about your last question: why there is no **outside destination** option? **ip nat inside source static** creates static NAT entry that translates exactly as you described, but this includes not only the traffic initiated from one particular side - static NAT entries are symmetrical. So, **ip nat outside destination static** would create a static entry for translating *destination* IP addresses of traffic entering into your network from the *outside* AND *source* IP addresses for traffic going from *inside* - but this is exactly what **ip nat inside source static** command does! So, it's simply redundant to have this command. The only difference is that you would interchange the source with the destination ip when using one or another form of basically the same command.

In regard to your first statement, "there are three possible combinations of inside/outside/source/destination that can be configured" - this is not quite so. The point is that, generally speaking, NAT configuration statements are not "math formulas" and should be considered wholly, and not as builded logically from independed keywords. So, each "combination" presents a solution for a particular task, for example, **ip nat inside destination list** is used for configuring server TCP load balancing that uses specific algorithm and does not work with UDP. Also, (in modern IOSes) there is no **ip nat inside destination static** command - have you actually tried it with the **static** option?

You can see some particular scenarios of using NAT including configuration examples in this Cisco paper: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipaddr_nat/configuration/12-2sx/nat-12-2sx-book/iadnat-addr-consv.html

Finally, I would like to mention that sometimes NAT is not what you want, for example, look at my answer for this "canonical question": https://serverfault.com/questions/55611/loopback-to-forwarded-public-ip-address-from-local-network-hairpin-nat/733532#733532

*PS Should I go into more details?*

Answer (score 7):

Think about this very carefully.

Inside source means that you want to translate the source address from traffic originating inside your network. This is the typical "home networking" arrangement which allows you to use private addresses on the public Internet. Of course, this is not the only use for this version.

Inside destination means that you want traffic originating from an outside address to a particular destination transport protocol and port to go to a particular inside address. This is what home users do to allow something like a web server with a private address to be accessed from the public Internet. Of course, this is not the only use for this version.

Outside source translates traffic originating from outside to look like it originated from an inside address. It can useful in cases where companies with overlapping IP address ranges merge and need to start connecting the networks. You can translate the source addresses of traffic originating from the outside, which would normally have outside source addresses which conflict with inside addresses, to source addresses addresses in an available inside address range.

Outside destination doesn't really make a lot of sense since it is the inverse of port forwarding. This would limit any traffic originating from the inside, destined to a particular outside transport protocol and port, to a single outside address.

Comment: Your description for `inside destination` seems to match my "layman's explanation" for `inside source`. Except, my example changed the destination port# for the inbound traffic from `80` to `8080`. Your description seems to imply the port# doesn't change? Either way, that can't be the only difference between `inside destination` and `inside source`, can it?

Comment: The difference is the source of the traffic. The `inside source` traffic flow originates on the inside, and the `inside destination` traffic flow originates from the outside. If traffic originating from`inside source` needs a reply, a temporary `inside destination`-type process happens for the reply. The port number can be changed as the traffic travels from  one side to the other, but not all routers (especially home routers) support this.